# Packet framing for very short serial packets

Tags: c, embedded, crc, serial-communication, error-detection

We designed simple fixed-length protocol for embedded device. Every packet is just two bytes:

```
 bits |  15..12  |    11..4     |  3..0   |
      |  OpCode  |     DATA     |  CRC4   |
```

We use "crc-based framing", i.e. receiver collects two bytes, compute CRC4 and if it matches frame is considered valid. As you can see, there is no start-of-frame or end-of-frame.

There is a catch: recommended message length for CRC4 is 11 bits and here it is computed for 12 bits. As far as I understand that means that CRC error-detection properties degrade (but I'm not sure how much).

(By the way, if anybody needs code for CRC4 (or any other) and does not feel skilled enough to write it himself, boost has very nice boost::crc function that can compute any crc )

The problem is: this crc-based framing doesn't work and we get framing errors, i.e. second byte from one message and first byte from the following message sometimes form correct message.

My question is - is there any way to correct framing without adding any more bytes? We spend quite some time squeezing everything in that two bytes and it would be kinda sad to just throw it away like that.
We do have a spare bit in opcode field though.

- Time-based framing will not be very reliable because our radio-channel likes to "spit" several packets at once
- Maybe there is some other error-detection method that will work better than CRC4?

It we have to append more bytes, what would be the best way to do it?

- We can use start-of-frame byte and byte-stuffing (such as COBS) ( +2 bytes but I'm not sure what to do with corrupted messages )
- We can use start-of-frame nibble and widen CRC to CRC8 ( +1 byte )
- Something else?

Comment: How are bits exchanged between the processor and the device?

Comment: @4386427 processor is connected to radio-transmitter by UART; radio-receiver is connected to the device by UART.

Comment: Are there a constant flow of packets?

Comment: @4386427 more or less. There is constant flow of 4 packets per second but there also can be sporadic packets in between.

Comment: In that case it is common to do packet framing over a number of packets, i.e. you need to see N consecutive packets with good CRC before you start accepting packets. Don't just rely on two single bytes for framing. That would be too error prone.

Comment: @4386427 that would increase reaction time from device which is very undesirable.

Comment: Yes, but that is necessary if you want reliable framing. You'll need a "training period" at start up to find the correct framing. For instance you may drop the first 8 packets right after start up to get into a stable FRAME state. After that you'll get all packets (until an error occur and you have to re-frame). It's a very common method and usually not a real problem as it only occurs at start up (and again after bit errors on the media). Check for instance PCM and ATM (cell delineation) protocols.

Comment: Why are you using UART for this in the first place? It's such an old and crappy technology. Is SPI an option? Also since you mention radio, CRC4 is most likely far too small to be of any use - radio disturbances will yield pretty much 100% random data through the whole package. If the radio has no built-in checksum mechanism, I'd use at least CRC16.

Comment: @Lundin UART and SPI are basically the same. Well, SPI is syncronious, so what? That doesn't make it any less error-prone. And it's not an option anyway. Radiomodules have checksums of their own, so our CRC is mostly for frame-synchronization and paranoia.

Comment: @4386427 thank you, we will consider this idea!

Comment: @Amomum The difference is that SPI is clocked at every bit, but UART is only clocked once per 10 bits. When data is clocked at every bit, there is always the option to investigate bit lengths to detect noise - a technique which is far superior to CRC. It is very unlikely that noise has the exact bit lengths of a single bit.

Comment: @Lundin 1) That actually depends on clock speed 2) We don't actually have problems with errors, our problem is frame synch and SPI won't help with it 3) I'm not sure how bit length can be measured if SPI peripheral is used for communication 4) If errors appear in data wires, SPI clock can also be corrupted and bit synch would be lost. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Amomum Depends on what the radio chip does. If it always transforms the serial data to some specialized protocol frame then the manner of serial bus doesn't matter. But if the radio chip is "dumb" and just relays the binary data passed to it, then UART is quite unsuitable. You would be looking for manchester encoding or a similar robust data format, which is possible to generate with SPI but not with UART.

Comment: @Lundin sorry, but I don't quite get what do you mean. Anyway, I don't really know what radiochip is actually doing (I presume it wraps our packets in some frames of its own and calculates some kind of checksum, but we sometimes receive fragments of packets ), I can't change it or change it's interface to SPI.

Comment: Small idea: Trade 1 bit/byte by using a 2-bit CRC and use those 2 bits for framing each of the 2 bytes.  Or additionally, send data using odd parity instead of no parity (10% slower) - that coupled with 2-bit CRC effectively is back to 4-bit CRC.

Comment: http://www.zlib.net/crc_v3.txt

Comment: @chux: I think this is all pretty opiniated and too broad.

Answer (score 4):

A common way to do what you are asking is to "hunt for framing" at start up and require N consecutive good packets before accepting any packets. This can be implemented using a state machine with 3 states: HUNT, LOF (loss of frame), SYNC

It could be something like:

```
#define GOOD_PACKETS_REQUIRED_BEFORE_SYNC 8
int state = HUNT;
int good_count = 0;

Packet GetPacket(void)
{
    unsigned char fb = 0;
    unsigned char sb = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        if (state == HUNT)
        {
            fb = sb;
            sb = GetNextByteFromUART();

            if (IsValidCRC(fb, sb))
            {
                state = LOF;
                good_count = 1;
            }
        }
        else if (state == LOF)
        {
            fb = GetNextByteFromUART();
            sb = GetNextByteFromUART();

            if (IsValidCRC(fb, sb))
            {
                good_count++;
                if (good_count >= GOOD_PACKETS_REQUIRED_BEFORE_SYNC)
                {
                    state = SYNC;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                state = HUNT;
                good_count = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (state == SYNC)
        {
            fb = GetNextByteFromUART();
            sb = GetNextByteFromUART();

            if (IsValidCRC(fb, sb))
            {
                return packet(fb, sb);;
            }

            // SYNC lost! Start a new hunt for correct framing
            state = HUNT;
            good_count = 0;
        }
    } 
}
```

You can find several standard communication protocols which use this (or similar) technique, e.g. ATM and E1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-carrier). There are different variants of the principle. For instance you may want to go from SYNC to LOF when receiving the first bad packet (decrementing good_count) and then go from LOF to HUNT on the second consecutive bad packet. That would cut down the time it takes to re-frame. The above just shows a very simple variant.

Notice: In real world code you probably can't accept a blocking function like the one above. The above code is only provided to describe the principle.

Whether you need a CRC or can do with a fixed frame-word (e.g. 0xB) depends on your media.

Comment: `Packet GetPacket()` is not correct or you forgot to return a value. Please use correct prototype-declarators. Actually the compiler should warn.

Comment: @Olaf - this is not a complete function (it would be a horrible implementation...) - it is just to show some principle. However, if all structs and (missing) function were implemented, I don't see why the prototype should be incorrect.

Comment: For a starter because it returns an `int`. Second it uses an old-style declarator which is an obsolecence feature and strongly deprecated. You might want to read the standard.

Comment: @Olaf - what makes you think it returns an int?

Comment: I don't think that. But the C compiler expects it. You should read the standard, what a missing type specifier in a function declaration means (and that it should not be used since ca. 27 years).

Answer (score 1):

> There is a catch: recommended message length for CRC4 is 11 bits and here it is computed for 12 bits.

No, here it is computed for 16 bits.

> As far as I understand that means that CRC error-detection properties degrade (but I'm not sure how much).

Recommendations about CRC likely refer to whether you have a 100% chance of finding a single-bit error or not. All CRCs struggle with multi-bit errors and will not necessarily find them.

When dealing with calculations about CRC reliability of UART, you also have to take the start and stop bits in account. Bit errors may as well strike there, in which case the hardware may or may not assist in finding the error.

> second byte from one message and first byte from the following message sometimes form correct message

Of course. You have no synch mechanism, what do you expect? This has nothing to do with CRC.

> My question is - is there any way to correct framing without adding any more bytes?

Either you have to sacrifice one bit per byte as a synch flag or increase the packet length. Alternatively you could use different delays between data bits. Maybe send the two bytes directly after each other, then use a delay.

Which method to pick depends on the nature of the data and your specification. Nobody on SO can tell you what your spec looks like.

> Maybe there is some other error-detection method that will work better than CRC4?

Not likely. CRC is pretty much the only professional checksum algorithm. The polynomials are picked based on the excepted nature of the noise - they pick a polynomial which reminds as little of the noise as possible. However, this is mainly of academic interest, as no CRC guru can know how the noise looks like in your specific application.

Alternatives are sums, xor, parity, count number of 1s etc... all of them are quite bad, probability-wise.

> It we have to append more bytes, what would be the best way to do it?

Nobody can answer that question without knowing the nature of the data.

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment to the polynomial part: Some polynomials are better at handling burst errors than random errors etc.. So there are some noise-characteristics you can tailor your crc polynomial towards. This CMU publication talks about polynomial selection in an embedded context: http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1672&context=isr

Comment: >>"No, here it is computed for 16 bits." No, it's 12 bits of data and 4 bits of CRC. I use boost::crc_basic and calculate bit by bit. >>"You have no synch mechanism, what do you expect?" As far as I know (but I'm not an expert) crc-based frame synchronization is a synch mechanism and it is used..https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRC-based_framing  >>"Nobody can answer that question without knowing the nature of the data." data byte can be any arbitrary byte.

Comment: @Amomum On the receiver side, the CRC is typically calculated both on data and on the FCS. I.e you XOR the whole packet against the polynomial and check if the result is 0 or not.

Comment: @Lundin is it any different from calculating CRC just for the data and comparing it to FCS in the packet?

Comment: @Lundin: The framing-bits are not part of the data and constant. Not sure if they add to the calculation of the CRC (and it does not for typical protocols). And the result is only zero if the CRC is not inverted (which is recommended). And it is also not a simple XOR.

Comment: @Amomum The difference is that you have to regard the FCS as part of the data.

Comment: @Lundin that's obvious. I meant is there any _practical_ difference? Any benefits?

Comment: @Olaf Traditionally CRC was calculated as bit-by-bit XOR and you can even do so with pure digital electronics. You can calculate it with bit-by-bit XOR in software too but that tends to be quite ineffective. Inverting the register before or after calculation is very CRC dependent. Some do, some don't. Why either would be better or worse isn't obvious... I doubt there's any rationale behind it, there's just different standards (or lack of a standard).

Comment: @Lundin: I'm well aware about the math behind CRCs and how they are calculated in hardware as well software. FYI: The reason to invert the CRC is to detect trailing 0-bits past the CRC. See e.g. Ethernet. The end-of-frame is detected by out-of-band signaling, so it is not clear until the end when the CRC has been received. So if the EOF-signal is handled from the PHY, and  CRC accumulator matches a specific "magic" code (it is not zero because of the inversion), the transmission was successful. There are quite good tutorials about this on the web.

Answer (score 1):

If the CRC is mainly for paranoia (from the comments), you can give up some  error-checking robustness and processor time for framing.

Since there is a free bit in the opcode, always set the most-significant bit of the first byte to zero. Then before transmission, but after calculating the CRC, set the most-significant bit of the second byte to one.

A frame is then two consecutive bytes where the first most significant bit is zero and the second is one. If the two bytes fail the CRC check, set the most significant bit of the second byte to zero and recalculate to see if the packet had the bit flipped before transmission.

The downside is that the CRC will be calculated twice about half of the time. Also, setting the bit for framing may cause invalid data to match the CRC.